# How do I catch signals?

Tags: error-handling

After reading the documentation, here's what I've tried:

```lisp
(condition-case err
    (signal 'my-error 'my-data)
  (my-error (message "data: %S" err)))
```

Evaluating this form still throws the signal, though – how can I truly catch it?

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but it seems that specific condition-case is duplicating a `with-demoted-errors`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define the symbol as an error first:

```lisp
(define-error 'my-error "Custom error")

(condition-case err
    (signal 'my-error 'my-data)
  (my-error (message "data: %S" err)))
```

Evaluating this form yields `"data: (tmp:error . my-data)"` as expected.

Comment: If my-error never leaves my functions, personally I would use a `catch` `throw` pair.

Comment: Good practice to follow. In this case (`cachey.el`), it's an error being signaled to the programmer – is `catch` still appropriate?

Comment: if it's an actual error, this answer is correct. I was just warning people not to use this strategy for navigating loops or anything.

Comment: @Malabarba +1 to that – I've seen it done… horrifying.